# preg_replace putting the final result in the wrong place

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

so I'm having issues getting `preg_replace` to work right. I'm trying to create my own custom `markdown`. I get the result I want since it seems to be coughing up what I wanted. However, the problem is that it spits the user input outside of the blockquote. Here is an example of what I am talking about.

Here's my code.

```
<?php
$user_input = '> My quote';

$syntax = array(
    '/>\s+(.*?)/is'
);

$replace_with_html = array(
    '<blockquote><h3>Quote</h3><p>$1</p></blockquote>'
);

$replaced = preg_replace($syntax, $replace_with_html, $user_input);

print($replaced);
```

Here's the user input.

```
> My quote
```

And here is the result.

```
<blockquote><h3>Quote</h3><p></p></blockquote>My quote
```

---

What I want is

```
<blockquote><h3>Quote</h3><p>My quote</p></blockquote>
```

As you can see, the user input is in the wrong placement (at the end of the final `HTML` code). Is there a way to possibliy fix this and place it within the paragraph tags?

Comment: The `?` wants to know where to end, either have it go to the end or allow it to be greedy, `>\s+(.*?)$` or `>\s+(.*)$`. Also note the `preg_replace` isn't moving the result, it is replacing what you told it, then adding the remainder. See https://regex101.com/r/Zvik0d/1/ for a visual example of how your regex is working.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make arrays, use this:

```
$user_input = '> My quote';

$syntax = '/>\s+(.*)/s';

$replace_with_html = '<blockquote><h3>Quote</h3><p>$1</p></blockquote>';

$replaced = preg_replace($syntax, $replace_with_html, $user_input);

print($replaced);
```

This works the same way: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/68e2f2ee3cf6985bedd0b7294f56030540b159fc))

```
$user_input = '> My quote';

$syntax = ['/>\s+(.*)/s'];

$replace_with_html = ['<blockquote><h3>Quote</h3><p>$1</p></blockquote>'];

$replaced = preg_replace($syntax, $replace_with_html, $user_input);

print($replaced);
```

Either way, you WANT the dot in the pattern to be **greedy**, remove the `?`.

Without this adjustment, you're only replacing the `>\s+` part of the pattern.

---

### That said, let me solve some problems that you haven't encountered yet...

1. How do you know where to stop quoting?
2. What if someone wants to use `>` to mean "greater than"?

Consider this new pattern and how it may help you tackle some future challenges:

`/^>\s+(\S+(?:\s\S+)*)/m` [Replacement Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PPJGB9/1)

In the demo link you will see that the pattern will match (after `>` and 1 or more spaces) one or more non-whitespace characters optionally followed by: a single whitespace character (this can be a space/tab/return/newline) then one or more non-whitespace characters.

Effectively this says, you want to continue matching "quote" text until there are 2 or more consecutive whitespace characters (or else to the end of the string).

This adjustment *should* give your users the ability to accurately/conveniently quote-format their text while appropriately leaving innocent `>` character alone.

Comment: The arrays are for mulitple `markups`. I didn't show the full array list because those aren't relevant at this point since those are actually returning the correct results. The only one that seems to be returning the input in the wrong place is the one for blockquotes.

Comment: Thanks. Removing the `?` in `(.*)` did the trick. I thought `(.*?)` was supposed to represent a string placeholder. I didn't know that `(.*)` could work without the `?`. Silly me.

Comment: @OliverTwist `.*?` is a series of 3 special regex characters. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html and http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: I bet the lesson learned will stick with you now.  A `?`, `*`, or `+` (or a curly bracketed expression using numbers) after a character in a pattern is the "quantifier" which dictates "how many to match".  If the quantifier is immediately followed by `?` or `+`, this tells the quantifier to "behave" a particular way -- respectively: "lazy" or "possessive".  Otherwise it will be greedy by default.

Comment: @OliverTwist I have updated my answer for you because I see trouble on the horizon.  Please click the demo link where I show some of the challenges that you may need to deal with.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks. Updated the old one and now I'm using the new one you posted. Works perfectly.